# MOLUSCE plugin is not available for QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, molusce

I have updated to QGIS 3.4 Madeira version.

However, I can't find [MOLUSCE plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/molusce/) for this new version.

Is it not available for newer versions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the [MOLUSCE plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/molusce/) is not updated for more than one year and half which means it works only in QGIS 2.x and not yet updated to be compatible with QGIS 3.x. Please look at the version tab in the above link. If you need to use this plugin, then it is better to use QGIS 2.18 and wait until the plugin being updated for QGIS 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Some Molusce papers. I think they are helpful.
https://www.mdpi.com/2073-445X/11/3/419
https://www.mdpi.com/2073-445X/12/2/340
https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/15/4/1148
https://www.mdpi.com/2073-445X/10/6/584

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/246264)

Answer (score 0):

MOLUSCE plugin is available only in an older version of QGIS. FYI, I tried QGIS 2.18 as many sources indicated, however, even though the plugin was installed it never produced any results, therefore, the QGIS version that worked for me was 2.14. By the way, this older version of QGIS only runs on Windows.